# How do I set my application to default on a rooted device

Tags: android

We have a tablet app that we're deploying at retail outlets. It currently self updates late at night but after it does it is no longer the default "home" application and the user is given the choice to start our app or the default launcher again. We'd like to always have our app be the default home application even after updates. Is there a way to do this on a rooted device?

This is an ICS based device so the addPreferredActivity doesn't seem to work as I cannot get the android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS permission even though the device is rooted. If there is a way around that, I think I could get this done..

Comment: I don't know if this is possible, but have you tried removing the default Launcher so that yours is the only one on the device?

Comment: I'd prefer to leave the rest of the device as stock as possible. I assumed there was some preference somewhere that controls the user's last "default app" selection.. since I have full control over the device I assumed I could get at this twiddly bit and set it to my heart's desire.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Is there a way to do this on a rooted device?

The simplest solution is the one you rejected from the comment: remove the stock launcher and make yours be the only launcher.

> This is an ICS based device so the addPreferredActivity doesn't seem to work as I cannot get the android.permission.SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS permission even though the device is rooted.

Root, by itself, has nothing to do with permissions. In this case, `SET_PREFERRED_APPLICATIONS` is a signature-level permission, meaning that your app would have to be signed by the same signing key as the firmware, which will not be possible unless you roll your own modded ROM.

If I am reading [the Android source code](http://androidxref.com/source/xref/frameworks/base/services/java/com/android/server/pm/Settings.java) correctly, the results of `addPreferredActivity()` wind up in `/data/system/packages.xml`, in a `<preferred-activities>` element. Play around with modifying that file **very carefully** and see if that will get you what you want.

Comment: I think I am on the right path.. I am able to update that file from my app, and pull the file and see that it has the correct contents (given a comparison with the way android itself modified the file previously). The only problem is that it seems to ignore the changed file. do you know how to force it to reload those preferred-activities, as it must be caching them in memory.

Comment: @danb: "The only problem is that it seems to ignore the changed file." -- oh, yeah. In hindsight, that's not surprising. "do you know how to force it to reload those preferred-activities, as it must be caching them in memory" -- yeah, I'm sure it is. That file is read when `PackageManagerService` is created, but the only way I know to force that code path is a reboot. While not ideal, since you have to manually fuss with the device after a self-upgrade (can't do that silently, needs user input), perhaps a reboot will suffice.

Comment: This worked, btw. When our app finishes updating itself, it now changes the packages.xml file and reboots the device and immediately starts our app, it's a very slick and painless upgrade.

Comment: I tried to dump this file on android 4.2.2, but there is no <preferred-activities> tag. Does someone know where it went? I definitely have some default apps set.

Comment: Found it in /data/system/users/0/package-restrictions.xml

Comment: @danb I'm trying to do the same but I'm not being able to open the package-restrictions.xml file programmatically. I get an IOException (Permission Denied). Tried modifying permissions but didn't work. Do you recall how you actually did it? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it happens that some application cant work properly in rooted device i also had same kind of problem in my device (was also Rooted).so i had only one way remain that to install os again so i did it with use of some software (like superoneclick) and with use of it i unroot my device and reinstall os. then the application works perfectly so may be u should also unroot your device if its possible.